# asp.net - Even click button when use of application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In aspx I have code flow :-

```
<button onclick="return StartLottory()" id="btnStart" class="btnAction"  Runat="server" onclick="return btnStart_onclick()">
```

And I have available Count :-

```
Application["Count"] = 1;
```

I want to catch even when anyone click on button "btnStart". Can you help me please?

Comment: two onclick()...??????

Comment: you need to write the return_StartLottory() method, since it is called when the button click occurs.

Comment: i think you want to count the button click, isn't it?

Comment: This code not run. :)

Comment: Yes, I want to count the button click.

Answer (score 0):

you have written two onclicks. 
and why dont you use asp.net`s button webserver control.

```
          <asp:button runat="server"  onclick="yourserversidefunction" onclientclick="yourclientsidefunction"/>
```

in above case you will need

```
       <button onserverclick="serversidefunction" id="btnStart" class="btnAction"  Runat="server" onclick="clientsidefunction">
```

hope i corrected your question

Solution:-

```
 protected void serversidefunction( object sender, Eventargs e)
 {
      Application["count"] +=1;
 }
```

tweak it as per your need. specially talking about this "Eventargs". i m not sure if it is eventargs or buttoneventargs.

Comment: I want to catch even at file .cs. Can you get more information.

Comment: see the solution given by Sujith Karivelil.

Comment: Error: I want to catch even on file javascript and file cs. My code: `<button onserverclick="serversidefunction" onclick="return StartLottory()" id="btnStart" class="btnAction" Runat="server" >` push error, not run.

Comment: I'm sorry, when click button, page was reload and event not run. I'm understand that. So I'll find new solution for this problem. Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

using vb.net

```
  Dim clicks as integer=0
  public Sub  return_StartLottory()
        clicks += 1
        MsgBox("Your click Count is :" & clicks)
  End Sub
```

using c#

```
int clicks = 0;
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    clicks += 1;
    Interaction.MsgBox("Your click Count is :" + clicks);
}
```